# Market on close script

Tags: pine-script

I'm using pine script to backtest a trading strategy and can't figure out how to have my position close at end of regular trading day. My script continues to run and fill orders in extending hours trading. I would like it to close any open position at the end of the regular trading session, so a buy or sell (depending on current position) Market on close oder.

Here's the timing part of my script. Appreciate any feedback on how to achieve a MOC order each day.
`

```
start = timestamp(2022,1,1,6,30,0)
end = timestamp(2022,11,16,1,0,0)
if time >= start and time <= end
    strategy.entry("buySignal",strategy.long,300.0, when = buySignal)
    strategy.entry("sellSignal",strategy.short,300.0, when = sellSignal)
    strategy.close("buySingnal", when = sellSignal)
    strategy.close("sellSignal", when = buySignal)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Concept from https://www.tradingview.com/v/mCOgJC67/

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

if session.isfirstbar
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)


closeAllAtEndOfRegularSession(series string comment = na, series string alertMessage = na) =>
    if session.islastbar_regular and barstate.isconfirmed
        strategy.close_all(comment = comment, alert_message = alertMessage, immediately = true)

closeAllAtEndOfRegularSession()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. My script is version 4. any suggestions on how to achieve this with code that's compatible with V4?

Comment: you can use `if session.ismarket[1] and session.ispostmarket` condition but it is less accurate

Comment: You can always convert your script to v5 using autoconverter in the script menu btw.

Comment: hahah, you just blew my mind and made me feel like a dumb a** at the same time. I'm new to pine and have been looking for a way to convert to v5. didn't know it was tight there in the menu. Thank you!